# Connecting and Persisting to HBase

Tags: java, hbase, datanucleus, apache-zookeeper, cloudera

I just tried to connect to hbase which is part of the cloudera-vm using a java client.

(192.168.56.102 is the inet ip of the vm)

I use virtual box with host only network setting.

So I can access the webUI of the hbase master @ http://192.168.56.102:60010/master.jsp

Also my java client (worked well on the vm itself) established connection to 192.168.56.102:2181

But when it calls **getMaster** I get **connection refused** see log:

```
11/09/14 11:19:30 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=192.168.56.102:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
11/09/14 11:19:30 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server /192.168.56.102:2181
11/09/14 11:19:30 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to cloudera-vm/192.168.56.102:2181, initiating session
11/09/14 11:19:30 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server cloudera-vm/192.168.56.102:2181, sessionid = 0x13267157f930009, negotiated timeout = 40000
11/09/14 11:19:32 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt 0 of 10 failed; retrying after sleep of 1000
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:567)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(HBaseClient.java:311)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:865)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC$Invoker.invoke(HBaseRPC.java:257)
    at $Proxy9.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:90)
    at org.datanucleus.store.hbase.HBaseUtils$1.run(HBaseUtils.java:432)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.datanucleus.store.hbase.HBaseUtils.createSchemaForClass(HBaseUtils.java:428)
    at org.datanucleus.store.hbase.HBaseMetaDataListener.loaded(HBaseMetaDataListener.java:74)
    at org.datanucleus.store.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.<init>(HBaseStoreManager.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:677)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:287)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:453)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:264)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory.initialiseNucleusContext(JPAEntityManagerFactory.java:746)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory.<init>(JPAEntityManagerFactory.java:422)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:91)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:150)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:70)
    at de.syrtec.jpa2hbase.start.TestDAO.main(TestDAO.java:13)
```

hbase-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>192.168.56.102</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2181</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.master</name>
        <value>192.168.56.102:60010</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="hbase-addressbook"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <properties>
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="hbase:192.168.56.102:60010" />
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionUserName" value="" />
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionPassword" value="" />
            <property name="datanucleus.autoCreateSchema" value="true" />
            <property name="datanucleus.validateTables" value="false" />
            <property name="datanucleus.Optimistic" value="false" />
            <property name="datanucleus.validateConstraints" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

TestDAO.java:

```
public class TestDAO {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hbase-addressbook");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction tx = null;

        Account a2 = new Account("myPre3", "mySur3", 2, new Login("e", "f"));

        tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin(); 
            em.persist(a2);
        tx.commit();
    }
}
```

just an addition of the network services running on the VM (netstat -ntpl):

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      563/sshd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      909/cupsd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8088            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2004/python2.6  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2345/python2.6  
tcp6       0      0 :::39087                :::*                    LISTEN      1327/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::54162                :::*                    LISTEN      1411/java       
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8020          :::*                    LISTEN      1411/java       
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8021          :::*                    LISTEN      1327/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::50070                :::*                    LISTEN      1411/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      563/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      909/cupsd       
tcp6       0      0 :::11000                :::*                    LISTEN      2077/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::43738                :::*                    LISTEN      858/java        
tcp6       0      0 :::50010                :::*                    LISTEN      858/java        
tcp6       0      0 :::51258                :::*                    LISTEN      858/java        
tcp6       0      0 :::50075                :::*                    LISTEN      858/java        
tcp6       0      0 :::60030                :::*                    LISTEN      1726/java       
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:44446         :::*                    LISTEN      1642/java       
tcp6       0      0 127.0.1.1:41246         :::*                    LISTEN      1726/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::8002                 :::*                    LISTEN      2009/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::8003                 :::*                    LISTEN      2009/java       
tcp6       0      0 127.0.1.1:58915         :::*                    LISTEN      1726/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::59203                :::*                    LISTEN      1491/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::50020                :::*                    LISTEN      858/java        
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      2077/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::2181                 :::*                    LISTEN      1726/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::9290                 :::*                    LISTEN      1327/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::60010                :::*                    LISTEN      1726/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::50090                :::*                    LISTEN      1491/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::10090                :::*                    LISTEN      1411/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::50060                :::*                    LISTEN      1642/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::50030                :::*                    LISTEN      1327/java
```

Comment: at least I got a Tumbleweed-Badge ^^

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After many tedious days of research I can provide a solution..could save others from a lot of headaches..

The root of the problem is the IPV6 support of Ubuntu (I'm using here).
But just deactivating IPV6 in the network administration wasn't enough.

Instead you have to append the following to the file: /etc/sysctl.conf

```
#disable ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

After reboot you should validate that IPV6 is really off by:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

(0 = IPV6 on ; 1 = IPV6 off)

Thanks a lot to

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/#disabling-ipv6

which gave me the crucial hint.