# Fully Distributed HBase Error

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm trying to setup HBase 0.96 to run on top of my Hadoop 2.2.0 cluster.  I run start-hbase.sh and the master along with the regions startup. I can log into each region and see the processes running. However when check to see how many regions are up either through the web ui or a shell command I get a response of 0. Based on the logs it looks like the region servers are starting up not unable to notify the master that they are running. I confirmed that the master is listening on port 60000 and ports 60000 along with 60020 are both open. I've included my hbase-site file along with the logs from a region server.

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://master:9000/hbase</value>
    <description>The directory shared by RegionServers.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>The mode the cluster will be in. Possible values are
      false: standalone and pseudo-distributed setups with managed Zookeeper
      true: fully-distributed with unmanaged Zookeeper Quorum (see hbase-env.sh)
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
   <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
   <value>master</value>
 </property>
  <property>
    <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
    <value>/master</value>
  </property>
```

Log File:

```
2013-11-08 20:08:58,357 INFO  [regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: reportForDuty to master=10.119.102.58,60000,1383941300240 with port=60020, startcode=1383941300420
2013-11-08 20:09:18,636 WARN  [regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: error telling master we are up
com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connec$
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.callBlockingMethod(RpcClient.java:1667)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(RpcClient.java:1708)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.RegionServerStatusProtos$RegionServerStatusService$BlockingStub.regionServerStartup(RegionServerStatusProtos.java:5402)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.reportForDuty(HRegionServer.java:1924)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:790)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending local=/100.65.$
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:532)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:493)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$Connection.setupConnection(RpcClient.java:573)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClient.java:858)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.getConnection(RpcClient.java:1532)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.call(RpcClient.java:1421)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.callBlockingMethod(RpcClient.java:1650)
        ... 5 more
2013-11-08 20:09:18,676 WARN  [regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: reportForDuty failed; sleeping and then retrying.
```

Comment: you definitely have a connectivity problem, check that rs and master actually listens on given IPs, not on localhost. and that hosts available to each other through network. (try something like telnet master 60000 )

Comment: Why your zookeeper quorum does not include region servers?!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `hbase.zookeeper.quorum` is set correctly, which may cause the connection timeout. If you just wan't to test 0.96, start it in standalone mode and then make sure the zookeeper cluster is running before you change to distributed mode.

Answer (score 0):

The HRegionServer complains that it can't connect to HMaster in order to report status (up).
It's probable that the HMaster process is not running so you may want to start it, or if you already started it to check the master log file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your master server is listening on port 60000 by using the following command 
netstat -l
tcp6        0      0 Vostro-350:60000        *:*              LISTEN

if the server is listening on ipv6 then disabled it.

To disable you have to append the following to the file: /etc/sysctl.conf

net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1 
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1 
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1

After reboot you should validate that IPV6 is really off by:

cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6

(0 = IPV6 on ; 1 = IPV6 off)

Ref link : [Connecting and Persisting to HBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414193/connecting-and-persisting-to-hbasethe)